# Magento 2.4 Category image lost after re-saving category backend

Tags: magento2, module, custom-attributes, magento2.4, magento2.4.0

After Migrating Magento 2.4 Category image lost after re-saving category backend issue How to i solve this ?

Comment: Did you get the solution?